# Exception thrown by application class 'java.lang.String.substring:1339' Websphere Liberty

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere-liberty

I am trying to run my app on websphere liberty. When I try to run my application I get the following error which was not present on Tomcat. I am trying to run netflix Eureka open source project (https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/da2f9e5bcf2503487a52d839093f039bea065af2/eureka-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/StatusFilter.java)

```
Exception thrown by application class 'java.lang.String.substring:1339'
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEncodedPath(ContainerRequest.java:377)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getPath(ContainerRequest.java:370)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1463)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:895)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:843)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:804)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at [internal classes]
at com.netflix.eureka.ServerRequestAuthFilter.doFilter(ServerRequestAuthFilter.java:34)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at [internal classes]
at com.netflix.eureka.StatusFilter.doFilter(StatusFilter.java:68)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
at [internal classes]
```

Does Websphere Liberty add some extra requests in their headers?

Comment: any other changes done between tomcat and wlp ? same URI base? no changes at all?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind no change at all

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: @Jens Updated the question with stacktrace

Comment: I would not expect the WebContainer in Liberty adding anything to the URI. What I would do is [enable trace of the WebContainer](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21384592) and see what the URI is that is getting processed. See the section on "Collecting Data Manually" for the trace strings to use.

Comment: @AlexandrePolozoff There isnt genHistoryReport.sh file in my bin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to Jersey v1.19 resolves the error.